# Mount file with 0600 permissions to podman

Tags: centos, permissions, mount, docker, podman

I have a problem with mounting file to `podman`. My file permissions is `0600` and it isn’t available to the container. If I use the `--privileged` option or volume propagation option `z` it is working. But my question is which of these options should I use? Or maybe there is another way to do this...

Let me describe you this case to avoid the XY problem. I want to generate certificate by `certbot` using DNS Cloudflare. I use Centos 8, so I have to do it by docker/podman. Cerbot needs a key to Cloudflare, so in `~/.secrets/clodflare` path I create `cloudflare.ini` file and I want to mount it to container.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to share some of my own experience I've learned these days. I am not an expert. I cannot suggest what should you do but can try to  explain what is happening when you run podman with `--privileged` and `:z`. Probably you've already known these.

I am assuming that you are running `podman` rootlessly, i.e., `podman -v` rather than `sudo podman -v`. I am also assuming that `~/.secrets/clodflare` is owned by you, with UID `1000`.

There are (at least) two permission issues in your case, namely, the traditional Unix permissions (`0600` or `-rw-------`) and SELinux (`container_file_t`, `user_home_t:`, `fusefs_t`, etc.).

- UNIX permission

  - in the container, the file/folder belongs to `root`. Therefore:
  - If the process in the container is run by `root`, then on the host, it is run by you. So it has the `rw-` permission to that folder/file. I think this is your case. It has nothing to do with `--privileged` nor `:z`.
  - If the procees in the container is run by another user, say with UID `1234`, then on the host, it is run by a user with UID `101233` (by default, based on the setting in `/etc/subid`). Therefore, it only has the `---` permission to that file. If you want to change the ownership to `1234` in the container (or `101233` on the host), you can run, e.g., `podman unshare chown -R 1234:1234 <path>` or `sudo chown -R 101234:101234 <path>`. However, I don't think this applies to you.
  - If on the host, the file does not belong to you, then in the container, it will belong to someone else according to the setting in `/etc/subid`.
  - you may find more on this topic by googling `podman namespace`.
- SELinux

  - on a SELinux enabled host, you still have the SELinux separation issue.
  - By using `--privileged`, you disable the SELinux separation (and more). But it will not relabel the file/folder. Everytime when you run podman, you should run it like `podman -v <host-path>:<container-path> --previleged <image>`.
  - by adding `:z`, you allow podman to relabel the file/folder. You only need to do this **once**. You can check the difference between before and after, by listing the file/folder via `ls -Z` or `ls -Zd`. Once the file or folder is relabeled properly, the next time you could just run `podman -v <host-path>:<container-path> <image>`, without `:z`, nor `--privileged`.
  - for more details about this issue, I cannot say much as it seems too complicated for me to understand. The man page of `podman run`, explanations on `--privileged`, `-v`, `-security-opt` are helpful.